# VirtualBox failure on install - Mac 10.14.5

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

On my Macbook Pro, I am trying to update my VirtualBox to the latest 6.0.8, or whatever the latest version is.  I end up with a failure on install.  I've tried the suggestions at https://medium.com/@DMeechan/fixing-the-installation-failed-virtualbox-error-on-mac-high-sierra-7c421362b5b5, but no luck.  I'm not a big mac user.  Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem?

TIA

Comment: As an FYI, I found resolution.  Yippee
Go into recovery mode on the mac and execute the instructions listed here:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/63337

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes.  The resolution was found in the link in the comment above.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following instruction worked for me:

Try restarting your workstation in Recovery Mode,
Access Terminal and enter the following command:

```
spctl kext-consent add VB5E2TV963
```

Restart your machine and retry the installation of VirtualBox.